# Jquery Real Person Error: <Object> has no method 'on'

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, recaptcha

I use the Jquery Real Person Recaptcha (http://keith-wood.name/realPerson.html).
It works, but "Click to change" o "Try another options" dont work and I have the error:

> Object # has no method 'on'

My code is:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en_US" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mousewheel-3.0.2.pack.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tickers.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.realperson.js"></script>
    <link href="css/jquery.realperson.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"/>

    <style type="text/css">
        .realperson-challenge { /*display: inline-block*/
            padding-top: 20px;
            padding-bottom: 20px;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('#defaultReal').realperson();
        });
    </script>
</head>
```

Anyone can help me? I don't see the error. There are 2 jquery includes but if i delete one of this the result is the same.

Thanks in advance

Stefania

Comment: You have to include at least jQuery version 1.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and it should do this

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method was added in jQuery 1.7 and you're using 1.4.2. There is no `on()` method in 1.4.2, so you'll either need to update your jQuery (http://jquery.com) or find a version of that plugin which works for versions of jQuery below 1.7.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: it's ok if I replace the old release with the last version?

Comment: @BebPratzaBallus you may have some issues depending on how much jQuery-requiring code you currently have on your site, but usually things are deprecated rather than outright removed. If you do directly update you should monitor your console and go through your site to see if any errors are thrown. Of course, you should also then optimise your jQuery code to conform. Methods like `on()` were added for a reason, for instance, so you may as well make use of them.